# Android : Try to let the android do the flow of my app as a user

Tags: android, ripple, demo

Am going to create a demo for my app flow 
What i need is to make the android click the buttons and perform actions as what the user supposed to do.  if i had a ripple layout for the button and need to show the ripple effect with the click action what should i do?!!
Here u are my test layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.testfloatedittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
        app:mrl_rippleColor="#585858"
        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
        app:mrl_rippleColor="#585858"
        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true" >

        <com.micromobs.android.floatlabel.FloatLabelEditText
            xmlns:floatlabel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/float_label_text_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            floatlabel:hint="Floating Label 1"
            floatlabel:textColorHintFocused="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
            floatlabel:textColorHintUnFocused="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```